# DateTime format not match to expected format in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012

After a hours of searching a solution to the problem i ask you for best answer : 
i am building a project  in ASP.NET 2013 and i get a date from dateTimePicker (JQUERY script)
i set it to format - dd/mm/yy and convert it to dateTime object in C# so the format in C# is : 
**dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS** and i send it to function insert it to SQL SERVER dataBse that expected to 
**MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS** format so the insert is faild and throw error   -

**The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

hope for quick solving the problem !

Thanks,
shaul.

Comment: Object of `DateTime` type hasn't any format. You can represent it in any format as you wish. To get better assistance you must show the part of code where you have trouble.

Comment: Give us some code, mainly the function that inserts into the database, with the function parameters

Comment: `and convert it to dateTime object in C# so the format in C# is : dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS` Wrong. No. DateTime in C# has a single underlying thing. It's the number of ticks (100 nanosecond units) since Jan 1, 0001. When you convert a DateTime object to a string, you can choose to represent it in any format. However, there is *no need* to convert it to a string to save it in the database, as SQL Server supports DateTime objects.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your date into date time format and then convert into `mm/dd/yyyy :HH:MM:ss` format and pass these date into your function.

Use below query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(convert(datetime,'2018-02-25 12:55:28.857') , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```